# App crashes when retrieving data after user input all data?

Tags: java, android

My code on how to retrieve data from the database. The data successfully saves in the database and suddenly my app crashes and the data can't be retrieved...

```
ViewAdsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if ((dataSnapshot.exists()))
            {
                String retrieveTuitionImage = dataSnapshot.child("adstuitionimage").getValue().toString();
                String retrieveTuitionName = dataSnapshot.child("adstuitioname").getValue().toString();
                String retrieveProviderName = dataSnapshot.child("adsprovidername").getValue().toString();

                Picasso.get().load(retrieveTuitionImage).placeholder(R.drawable.photocamera).into(ViewTuitionImage);

                ViewTuitionName.setText(retrieveTuitionName);
                ViewProviderName.setText(retrieveProviderName);
            }

            else
            {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
```

Logcat shows below:-

> 08-26 12:17:16.345 15709-15709/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>       SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   08-26 12:17:17.126 15709-15709/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   08-26 12:17:17.127 15709-15709/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   08-26 12:17:40.366 15709-15709/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>       SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   08-26 12:18:23.902 15709-15709/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem, PID: 15709
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem.ViewAdsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>           at com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem.ViewAdsActivity.onCreate(ViewAdsActivity.java:60)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6860)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is taking the current user which was just uploaded:

```
ViewAdsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Advertisements").child(intent.getStringExtra("UserKey"));
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

The error log said that your called `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` on a object that have not been initialized (null value) inside `ViewAdsActivity`.

I guess may be `getActionBar()` return null?

See: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Adda You're welcome! If my answer is correct, please consider mark it as accepted. 
Happy coding!